# Counting zeros of list from twin primes calculation

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory

```
twinPs[n_] = If[(Prime[n + 1] - Prime[n]) == 2, {Prime[n], Prime[n + 1]}, 0]
alst = Table[twinPs[x], {x, 41}]

{0, {3, 5}, {5, 7}, 0, {11, 13}, 0, {17, 19}, 0, 0, {29, 31}, 0, 0, \
{41, 43}, 0, 0, 0, {59, 61}, 0, 0, {71, 73}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {101, 103}, \
0, {107, 109}, 0, 0, 0, 0, {137, 139}, 0, {149, 151}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ 
{179, 181}}
```

How to make a count zeros list. ie. Return the length of a gap between successive pairs of twin primes?

```
answer = {1,1,1,2,2,3,2,5,1,4,1,5}
```

Comment: Have you seen http://oeis.org/A048614? But this creates the evaluation, not computed from my alst.

Comment: Search OEIS for 2,3,3,4,3,6,2,5,2,6 is interesting about Twin Primes, also.

Comment: May not be an elegant solution but here is one way `If[MemberQ[#, 0], Length@#, Nothing] & /@ Split@alst`

Comment: not sure how fast it is, but check out: `Length /@ SequenceSplit[alst, {{_, _}}]`

Comment: `DeleteCases[Count[#, 0] & /@ Split@alst, 0]`

Comment: similar to my other one, but a bit different: `Length /@ SequenceCases[alst, {0 ..}]`

Comment: and another one just for fun :) this one also counts length 0 runs of zeros, i.e. when two twin prime pairs are consecutive `Flatten[(Composition @@ Replace[alst, {0 -> (# + {1, 0} &), {_, _} -> ({0, #} &)}, 1])[0]]`

Comment: People, post answers!! These are full answers, so they should not be just comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Split` and `Cases`:

```
Cases[Split@alst, a:{0..} :> Length@a]
(* {1,1,1,2,2,3,2,5,1,4,1,5} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

twinPs[n_] = 
  If[(Prime[n + 1] - Prime[n]) == 2, {Prime[n], Prime[n + 1]}, 0];
alst = Table[twinPs[x], {x, 41}];

answer = SequenceCases[alst, {p : Repeated[0]} :> Length[{p}]]

(* {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {0, {3, 5}, {5, 7}, 0, {11, 13}, 0, {17, 19}, 0, 0, {29, 31}, 
   0, 0, {41, 43}, 0, 0, 0, {59, 61}, 0, 0, {71, 73}, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {101, 103}, 0, {107, 109}, 0, 0, 0, 0, {137, 139}, 
   0, {149, 151}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {179, 181}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Length /@ SequenceSplit[list, {_List}]
```

{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {0, {3, 5}, {5, 7}, 0, {11, 13}, 0, {17, 19}, 0, 0, {29, 31}, 
   0, 0, {41, 43}, 0, 0, 0, {59, 61}, 0, 0, {71, 73}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, {101, 103}, 0, {107, 109}, 0, 0, 0, 0, {137, 139}, 
   0, {149, 151}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {179, 181}};
```

This is a minor rephrase of Bob Hanlon's answer featuring `Cases`. Also compare with @thorimur's comment.

```
SequenceCases[list, k : {0 ..} :> Length@k]
```

---

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5}

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
  {0, {3, 5}, {5, 7}, 0, {11, 13}, 0, {17, 19}, 0, 0, {29, 31}, 
   0, 0, {41, 43}, 0, 0, 0, {59, 61}, 0, 0, {71, 73}, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {101, 103}, 0, {107, 109}, 0, 0, 0, 0, {137, 139}, 
   0, {149, 151}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {179, 181}};
```

---

Using `Split` and `DeleteCases`:

```
Length /@ DeleteCases[Split[list], {{__}}, ∞]

(*{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Length /@ Split[Flatten[Position[list, 0,1]], #2 - #1 == 1 &]

(* {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5} *)
```